# Hibernate Query Language error using 'is null'

Tags: hibernate

I'm using following Hibernate query and getting error. Product has one To Many relationship with tweeter so type for p.tweets is "List" .

Query:

```
@NamedQuery(
    name="getAllProductsWithNoTweets",
    query="From Product p where p.tweets is null"
)
```

Error is:

```
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'is'.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query makes no sense. A OneToMany will never be null. It might be empty, but not null.

If you want to get all the products without any tweet, the query should be something like

```
select p from Product p where p.tweets is empty
```

Answer (score 1):

Since p.tweets is a collection you might want to try `is empty`

Another thought is that you probably have to do a `left join` because if there are no tweets and you are joining on the tweet table then you simply won't get that product back in the results.

```
select p
from Product p
    left join p.tweets t
having count(t) = 0
```